# Объединение двух таблиц с одинаковыми названиями ячеек

Tags: php, mysql, sql

есть 2 таблицы

**t1**

- id name
- 1  aaa
- 2  bbb
- 3  ccc

**t2**

- id name
- 1  qwe
- 2  asd
- 3  zxc

нужно выбрать все по ключу **id** и чтобы **t1.name** стало **name1** и **t2.name** стало **name2**

**и получить**

- id name1 name2
- 1  aaa   qwe
- 2  bbb   asd
- 3  ccc   zxc

Comment: `SELECT * FROM t1,t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.id`

Comment: @Akina - спасибо за отзыв но это не то о чем я спрашивал...

Comment: Это называется _алиас_ `select t1.name as name1, t2.name as name2`

Comment: @Mike Спасибо огромное (: